# Separar elementos de un vector de acuerdo a su tipo

Tags: php, array

Necesito separar los elementos de un `array` de acuerdo a sí es **número**, **texto** y **alfanumérico** pero no se imprimen los alfanumericos :(

```
<?php
$d[0] = 13;
$d[1] = 133;
$d[2] = 45;
$d[3] = "Hice 89 lagartijas";
$d[4] = 778;
$d[5] = 67;
$d[6] = "Que onda";
$d[7] = 456;
$d[8] = 34;
$d[9] = 645;

$indiceNumeros = 0;
$indiceLetras = 0;
$indiceAlfaNumericos = 0;
for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){
  switch($d){
      case is_numeric($d[$i]):            
          $s[$indiceNumeros] = $d[$i];
          $indiceNumeros++;
          break;
      case is_string($d[$i]):
          $k[$indiceLetras] = $d[$i];
          $indiceLetras++;
          break;
       case ctype_alpha($d[$i]):
           $a[$indiceAlfaNumericos] = $d[$i];
           $indiceAlfaNumericos++;
           break;
       
  }
}
echo "Numeros <BR>";

for($i = 0; $i<count($s); $i++){
  echo "$s[$i] <br>";
}
echo "<br> Textos <BR>";

for($i = 0; $i<count($k); $i++){
  echo "$k[$i] <br>";
}
echo "<br> Alfanuméricos <BR>";
for($i = 0; $i<count($a); $i++){
  echo "$a[$i] <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos, el problema sucede por lo siguiente:

Los textos como los alfanuméricos al pasar a la función is_string van a retornar verdadero. Por esto es que en ninguno de los casos llega al tercer case.

Otro punto a considerar es que la función ctype_alpha sirve es para determinar si todos los elementos de una cadena de textos son letras del alfabeto, de la A a la z.

Por lo que el segundo case puedes colocar esa función para contar los textos y el en tercer case colocar la negación de ctype_alpha (!ctype_alpha) para contar los valores con letras y números.

Disculpa que no coloque código pero estoy desde el teléfono